# Function "assert" could not be resolved

Tags: c++, assert

I am trying to write a simple code for testing a "create function" but when I use `assert` I get this error: *function assert could not be resolved.*

This is my code:

```
#include "Participant.h"
#include "ParticipantValidator.h"
#include <assert.h>

void testCreateParticipant()
{
    Participant part(1, "Corina", "Marin", 5);
    assert(part.getId() == 1);
    assert(part.getScore() == 5);
    assert(part.getName() == "Corina");
    assert(part.getFamilyName() == "Marin");
}
```

Comment: Why not use a unit testing framework - ie boost_unit or cpp unit for example

Comment: @EdHeal: Maybe because assertions are not just for testing but are also useful in production builds.

Comment: @user3316022: Try to isolate the error by reproducing the error in a self-contained, compilable example. If the contents of Participant.h are not too big, include them manually. Check if ParticipantValidator.h is relevant at all. Remove if not. Ideally, you come up with a complete program with a `main()` function copy-n-pastable in a single *.cpp file that roughly fits on one browser screen :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `assert()`. It's a macro instead. You probably have included a wrong version of assert.h or in one of your previously included files is a `#define` that is evaluated as an include guard in assert.h.

- Check what include files (incl. absulote path) you really have included.
- Try to use `assert` in an example without the other header files.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you should [`#include <cassert>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) instead of `#include <assert.h>`.

Comment: Makes no difference w.r.t. macros.

Comment: @200_success: Why? Provide a reason.